# Order foreach results into 2 columns

Tags: php, css, arrays, foreach

I am attempting to style a list of results from a foreach into two columns, however I'm not too sure how to go about it without throwing off the PHP.

Currently, everything looks like below:
[image: current layout]

and I would like it to look so:
[image: wanted layout]

Currently, my foreach and CSS looks thus:

```
<p class="title">Reviews</p>
            <section id="reviews">
                <ul class="section_body">
                    <?php
                        foreach($reviews['reviews'] as $rv){
                            if ($rtmp++ < 10);
                            if ($rv['freshness'] == 'fresh') {
                               $image = "fresh";
                            }
                            else {
                                $image = "rotten";
                            }

                            echo '<img src="assets/images/' . $image . '.png" class="rating" title="Rotten" alt="Rotten" />';
                            echo '<li>' . $rv['quote'] . '</li>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </section>
```

[image: Current CSS]

Thank you in advance to anyone who may be able to help! It will be very gratefully received.

Comment: You can define a div for each review entry and specify its some constant width(which should be slightly less than the half of the total width) and have `float:left`

Comment: Giving your `#reviews li` the style `display: inline-block;` and then a width of 50% should accomplish what you need. You may need to also give them a fixed height to make them stack properly.

Answer (score 1):

I normally use css to do this kind of task to let the browser take care of stuffs

```
#reviews li
{
  float:left;
  width: 45%;
  ...
}
```

add those 2 lines to your css and let browser takes care of the arrangement. The idea is having each li take half of the container (50%). I made it 45% to take care of extra padding, margin and border

Also, your quote and image should be in the li

```
 <li> <img src="..." />  <span>my quote here</span>  </li>
```

Comment: Note that this may produce stacking issues if some elements are noticably taller than others.

Comment: that's true of course. OP may have to cater for that too e.g. giving each li a specific height

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<section id="reviews">                
<?php
$i=0;
foreach($reviews['reviews'] as $rv)
{
    if($i++%2 == 0)
    {
        echo '<ul class="section_body">';
    }
    if ($rtmp++ < 10);
    if ($rv['freshness'] == 'fresh') {
       $image = "fresh";
    }
    else {
        $image = "rotten";
    }

    $img =  '<div><img src="assets/images/' . $image . '.png" class="rating" title="Rotten" alt="Rotten" /></div>';
    echo '<li>' .$img . $rv['quote'] . '</li>';

    if($i%2 == 0 || $i== count($reviews['reviews']))
    {
        echo '</ul>'
    }
}
?>
</section>
```

You should put image and review text inside the li element.